# Magento2 css taking ages to load

Tags: css, render, page

I am creating a custom theme and the page always renders without the css formatting for about 10 seconds before loading properly.

Is this a configuration issue?

Answer (score 0):

For the first page load in developer mode it always takes ages because all the files / symlinks under pub/static have to be created on the fly.

If it takes that long on every load, it might be a configuration issue. Did you maybe configure Client Side Less Compilation under Stores -> Configuration -> Developer? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html

In this case Magento delivers the less files to the browser and the browser has to compile them on every load. This takes time and could explain this behaviour.

It might be a faster workflow to compile the less files "by hand" and directly upload the css files to the correct location under pub/static